# how to get most frequent words.from given string?

Tags: java, regex, string, for-loop

I am relatively new at java. I'm learning by myself how to use hashmaps, I came with a question with how to find the top three words in a string but the issue is removing the punctuation in the String- double spaces, commas... the current code only works for one space which is where the split() function is located.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s="a a a  b  c c  d d d d  e e e e e";
        int max=0;
        String maxs="";
        List<String> three= new ArrayList<String>();
        HashMap<String, Integer > top= new HashMap<String, Integer> ();
        for(String i : s.split(" ")){
            if(top.containsKey(i)) {
                top.replace(i,top.get(i)+1);
            }
            else {
                top.put(i,1);
            }
        }
      for(int i=0; i<=2;i++) {
        max=0;
        maxs="";
            for(String j: top.keySet()) { //string(word):all the values together
              if(top.get(j)> max ) {
                max=top.get(j);
                maxs=j;
              }
              
            }
              three.add(maxs);
              top.remove(maxs);
        }    
}
}

}
```

most frequent words?

Comment: also another question, if i want to remove all punctuation but not ones that are connected to words, for example won't - here I don't want the ' to be removed if its wont ' then I want it to be removed. ?

Comment: it seems that the answer was removed, if you add it back I can check to see if it works.

Comment: You are asking 2 questions: 1) how to remove punctuation except when within a word, and 2) how to get most frequent words. Please edit your question to narrow it to 1 problem, and remove all code not directly required to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...the issue is removing the punctuation in the String- double spaces,
> commas...

Given below is how you can replace all punctuations with a whitespace character and then replace the multiple consecutive whitespace characters with a single whitespace character:

1. First replace all punctuation characters with a whitespace character by using `str.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}", " ")` where `\p{Punct}` specifies a [punctuation character](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) which is one of !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~.
2. Chain the output of this replacement and replace `\\s+` with `" "` where `\\s+` specifies [one or more](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html) whitespace characters.

**Demo:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "a    b c d; e     f.   g=t";
        str = str.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}", " ").replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
a b c d e f g t
```

### Update (based on the OP's comment):

You have wished to retain `'` while removing all other punctuation marks. You can use `[^\p{L}\d']` as the regex pattern to be replaced. The regex pattern, `[^\p{L}\d']` means not a letter and not a digit and not a `'`. The `^` inside `[]` works as the negation pattern.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "a    won't c d; e     f.   g=t";
        str = str.replaceAll("[^\\p{L}\\d']", " ").replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
a won't c d e f g t
```

Comment: what about "won't" here I wouldn't want the ' to be removed because otherwise, it would change the word to won and t.

Comment: @GilCaplan - I have posted an update which should fulfil this requirement.

Comment: ok. thanks. just saw it now